# What is the best way to specify execution time of recurring jobs or tasks?

Tags: .net, logic, scheduled-tasks, recurrence

I am looking for a way of efficiently specifying a recurring job execution time without having to write an explicit execution time to a datastore. In other words, rather than saying 'job x next runs at 13.00pm on 11.12.08' and then having to update the execution time for the following week once the job has run, I want to be able to say 'job x runs at 13.00pm every thursday'. I need to be able to specify a recurrence range of anything from a few minutes to once per month. My guess is the shorter the recurrence period, the more difficult this becomes. Any ideas?

Note: I'm not looking for advice on the scheduling **mechanism**. I cannot use Windows Scheduler, Cron or create a Windows Service (I have no choice but to use a background thread in ASP.NET).

Answer (score 3):

I have seen cron expressions used widely for doing this, it might work well as an internal representation format.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with kamal that Cron is probably the simplest solution to configuring a scheduler.  It is very flexible - you can configure it to do just about anything (within reason).

I've used [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) for scheduling in the past.  It provides a CronTrigger - see the tutorial.  You could create a thread in your web app that runs the Quartz scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented some unattended services (Windows Services written in c#), using cron to manage the scheduling. The pattern is powerful, and flexible. We can create schedules to any time we want, only using the cron expression. Maybe I am wrong, but the only schedule that I think cron doesn't cover is if we want the last day of the month, but this was never a requirement for all services.

I copied the cron algorithm from an article in the internet (open source by Atif Aziz), and implemented in my utility class, working beautifully for years.

See more details in my blog: 
[CronTab schedule parser algorithm](http://blog.robertolopes.com/2010/11/17/crontab-schedule-parser-algorithm/)

Cheers!

Roberto